# What are the cost associated for Snowflake Caching?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does snowflake charges storage cost for result cache, warehouse cache and metadata cache?

Answer (score 1):

While I find the official answer, these are the principles behind each:

- Result cache: Available across warehouses, hence its persisted on cloud storage and should count within your storage costs.
- Warehouse cache: Available within an active WH, hence the cost is already included in the WH costs.
- Metadata cache: Naturally available throughout the cloud services layer. Free unless "Snowflake credits are used to pay for the usage of the cloud services that exceeds 10% of the daily usage of the compute resources".

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html

Comment: Hi Felipe, Thank you so much for your answer, even I thought the same but did not find any valid document on this. So thought of asking some expert on this for clarification